# which one is faster/better strcasecmp() or equal to operator?

Tags: php

I have to compare two strings for case insensitive equality  which one is faster strcasecmp() or equal to operator

```
$str1='Hello';
$str2='hello';

//first approach 
if($str1 != strotolower($str2))
    //do some stuff here

//second approach 
if(strcasecmp($str1,$str2) !=0)
    //do some stuff here)
```

which approach is better/faster?

Comment: I'd suggest using `$str1 != strotolower($str2)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 - why suggesting the slower one?

Comment: Are you planning on doing it for a significant amount of data?

Comment: Unless you are doing it on a million data, it doesn't matter.

Comment: not on large data, I will be comparing URLS and their subparts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both approaches are o(n) in speed however usign strtolower allocates a new string to hold the result which in turn increases memory pressure and reduces performance

Comment: thanks @Polity, I will go with the second approach of using strcasecmp() function

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
    //*********************************
    $start1 = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; ++$i) {
        if (strcasecmp('STRING1', 'string1') == 0) {}
    }
    $end1 = microtime(true);
    echo 'Time1: ' . ($end1 - $start1) . '<br/>';
    //*********************************
    $start2 = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; ++$i) {
        if (strtolower('STRING1') == strtolower('string1')) {}
    }
    $end2 = microtime(true);
    echo 'Time2: ' . ($end2 - $start2) . '<br/>';
    //*********************************
    $start3 = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; ++$i) {
        if (strtolower('STRING1') == 'string1') {}
    }
    $end3 = microtime(true);
    echo 'Time3: ' . ($end3 - $start3) . '<br/>';
    //*********************************
```

Result:

> Time1: 2.8758139610291
>
> Time2: 4.6863219738007
>
> Time3: 2.5191688537598

Comment: Please, check this sol. too 
http://www.alwaysgetbetter.com/blog/2013/09/29/comparing-strtolower-strcasecmp-caseinsensitive-string-checking-php/

Comment: Interesting, I'd not have guessed that strcasecmp is that fast. Thanks