# How to ignore character case of attribute's value?

Tags: php, xmldom

I'm using cURL to fetch META Description of a web page. Here's the fraction of the code:

```
   $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

   for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);
        $metaname = $meta->getAttribute('name');
        if($metaname == 'description')
              $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    <META name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

It works ok, but not perfectly. The problem happens when the character case of an element's attribute or value is different from what was defined. For example, the code above would not output the content values if the META attribute "name" or its value "description" is uppercase(NAME,DESCRIPTION) or capitalized(Name,Description).

How do I work around this without too much codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try php's `strcasecmp()`

**Example**

```
if (strcasecmp($metaname, 'description') == 0) {
     //equals
}
```

And, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905647/1114506), `strcasecmp()` and `strtolower()` approaches are o(n) in speed however using `strtolower()` allocates a new string to hold the result which in turn increases memory pressure and reduces performance

[PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

Comment: I just discovered that the problem can also happen to any element that I try to fetch. Is there any single line of code that can take care of it for all elements on the page instead of duplicating it for each of them?

Comment: I dont think that is possible, because PHP does not know which ones to convert unless it actually reads them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtolower to make all characters small case of **$metaname**
Modify your IF-condition to the following

```
if(strtolower($metaname) == 'description')
$description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: I just discovered that the problem can also happen to any element that I try to fetch. Is there any single line of code that can take care of it for all elements on the page instead of duplicating it for each of them?